# MarkLogic : Archiving data to different collection

Tags: marklogic

I have MarkLogic database setup and would like to archive data from one collection to another and make sure that Path Range Index ignores data to be picked up from new archive collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term 'collection' in MarkLogic is related to grouping of documents as in  - being a member of one or more groups and is done under the hood like a value in a range index. It is not actually an exclusive container of documents. In a single database, collections do not come into play in terms of path range indexes since a collection is not part of the referenced path information. All data in the database matching the path will be indexed regardless of it's membership in any particular collection. You could always consider modelling your data in a way that allowed for more control on what is indexed.

Currently, I think your options are all related to excluding them at the time of searching:

1. Use the collection('some collection name') as the searchable expression(xQuery)
2. Isolate the proper collections using a cts:collection-query() as part of your searches. How you would use this depends on how you are searching for your content(Java, REST, node.js, sjs, xQuery, search library, etc) - but in the end, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to constrain search results, look at the answer from David.

If you are trying to save disk space, you'll have to push your data into a different database to get it excluded from indexes.

Alternatively, you could consider pushing older data to slower/cheaper storage using MarkLogic's Tiered-storage capabilities. Here is a short blog article that discusses these: [Optimizing Cost and Access with Tiered Storage](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/tiered-storage)

HTH!

Comment: Another option for more control would be for MarkLogic to allow a flag of 'don;t index' on a forest.. With time-based queries on forest membership of documents (tiered storage / Ml9, I believe), you could then marshal content into and out of non-indexed forests. This could be usefl for staging or archiving.

Comment: Possibly, could be worth an RFE. On other hand, if you don't index the data, you can't search through it. Why keep it inside the database then? You can already push it to a particular forest using tiered-storage, and then backup, detach, and remove specific forests if you like.